# React doesn't display images placed in public folder when I install gh-pages but when I push the code it displays in gh-pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I have changed the images path from this src={`../images/${props.data.coverImg}`}

To this
src={`images/${props.data.coverImg}`}

and the interesting thing is that when I install gh-pages, images are broken on local host-3000 but it displays on gh-pages.

I have stored images folder in public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `./` before the img src:

```
 src={./images/${props.data.coverImg}}
```

I think there is a differnets in the way your browser rendering the url of the images, between localhost and a real environment.

Comment: I have tried that, but still not working, I have created an array of objects where I have mentioned the images name, and I'm dynamically accessing them  src={images/${props.data.coverImg} and the image folder is in public, it happens when I install gh-pages. is there any other way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947474/dynamically-loading-local-images-with-reactjs

Comment: Still not working man!

<img src={`images/${props.data.coverImg}`} className='card-img'/>
      <div className='card-stats'>
         <img className='card-star' src="images/star.png" alt="Star" />
        
Array of Objects

coverImg: "usa.png",
        stats: {
            rating: 5.0,
            reviewCount: 6
        }
and image folder is in public and I'm using props to access the images