# Require inside a react component error 'Cannot find module'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, require

I am trying to require pictures from local path:

```
{userImages.map((image) => {
                  return (
                    <Carousel.Item key={image.id}>
                      <Card.Img src={require(image.picture)} />
```

The value inside the variable looks like this:

```
../../media/female/f1.jpg
```

The error I am receiving:

```
Cannot find module '../../media/female/f1.jpg'
```

I tried another solution to require before the return like this:

```
const pic = require(userImages[0].picture);
```

still received the same error.
If I user require at the top of the component's file it does require correctly from this path.

Comment: Can you try `<Card.Img src={require(image.picture).default} />`

Comment: Tried it, same error.

Comment: Try if any of this work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947474/dynamically-loading-local-images-with-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Loading Local Images with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947474/dynamically-loading-local-images-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution from this link : [Dynamically Loading Local Images with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947474/dynamically-loading-local-images-with-reactjs)

it was to create context for the folder of images first at the top of the file like this:

```
const maleImages = require.context("../../media/male", true);
const femaleImages = require.context("../../media/female", true);
```

Then within the return include the image like this:

```
{userImages.map((image) => {
                  let img;
                  switch (user.gender) {
                    case "female":
                      img = femaleImages(image.picture);
                      break;
                    case "male":
                      img = maleImages(image.picture);
                      break;
                    default:
                  }
```

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to do something like this:

1. `import imageSource from "../../media/male/m1.jpg"`
2. `<Card.Img src={imageSource} />`

Comment: The path are generated randomly, so I dont know which path will be sent in advance to hard code it

Comment: Did you add a relative path relative to the file that `Card.Img` is in?

Comment: Yes tried to change the path to be relative to Card.Img and tried with the parent component.

Comment: Try to use hardcoded path, using `require()`. If image is not displaying, then it is an issue with path.